# Cron jobs creating blank file

Tags: php, cron

Cron jobs I created is automatically creating a blank file every time it's run.

Is there a way to fix this issue so that it doesn't create this file?

Below is the command for cron jobs:

```
/usr/bin/wget http://nitelife.wmetools.com/backend/index.php/ratings/overall_ratings_history
```

Comment: I get a blank page when I access: http://nitelife.wmetools.com/backend/index.php/ratings/overall_ratings_history (GET overall_ratings_history  200 OK  nitelife.wmetools.com  0  111.67.13.57:80)

Comment: Is the cron job creating the file or is it the PHP code? My guess is the code.

Comment: wget command line argument --delete-after

Answer (score 1):

It's downloading an empty file because that's what that URL gives you. If you are sure and/or don't care about the possibility that some day, that URL may send some data (like some kind of infrequent message, like an error), add "-O /dev/null" to the wget command line. That will make sure that wget never writes a real file at all. If there's a 4xx or 5xx error message, you'll still get something over standard error into an email from cron, but if any message comes via a normal HTML over a 200 response, it would be lost.

That raises the question though, why "wget" that link in the first place? If you just want the .php script to run and don't care about its output, I suppose the first suggestion is sufficient. Otherwise, you may need a short script, which would use -O to write to a temp file, and test for a non-zero file size ("-s" in bash) and then move the file to the correct location, or delete the 0-length file. That way the normal location would only have the file from the last time it had any data in it.

If that PHP file is yours, you could edit it so that it doesn't give an 200 status code and 0 length document anymore. There's a rarely used "204 No Content" HTTP status code. I haven't tested wget with a 204, but it really shouldn't save a file in that case, nor should it be considered an error.

Answer (score 0):

Following will delete the file created by wget.

```
/usr/bin/wget -q --delete-after http://nitelife.wmetools.com/backend/index.php/ratings/overall_ratings_history
```

You may lose the information in these files.